# Sanitizing errors sent thru url

Tags: php, security, xss

Ok quick question. I am sending errors through URL in intergers only

`(../index?err=4)`

then when it gets there I am filtering that error with

```
$errorget = filter_input(
    INPUT_GET, 'err', $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
);
```

I then use a switch to select appropriate echo.

```
switch ($errorget) {
    case "4":
        $error = 'Error1';
        break;
    case "61":
        $error = 'Error2';
        break;
    case "33":
        $error = 'Error3';
        break;
    case '51':
        $error = 'Error4';
        break;
    default:
        $error = null;
}
echo $error;
```

Ok so, is this a safe method and is there a vulnerability with this way to help avoid XSS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don’t you print the error message on the page they happen?

Comment: functions in external page

Answer (score 0):

If you're seriously worried about it being a number, just cast it as such

```
$errorget = (int)$_GET['err']; //this is always a number
```

Next, this really isn't a candidate for XSS attacks because you're not outputting the data anywhere (i.e. `echo $_GET['err']`). Providing bad data in this case will simply do... nothing. As in `$error = null;` Providing a list of what should happen on the other end avoids XSS entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Machavity writes about int case and XSS vulnerability, I would recommend not to use a switch/case for something as simple as printing an error message but to use an array instead:

```
$errorMessages = array(
    4  => 'Error1',
    61 => 'Error2',
    33 => 'Error3',
    51 => 'Error4',
);

echo $errorMessages[$errorget];
```

Output (with `$errorget == 61`):

```
Error2
```